# Update range request returns 200 OK but doesn't update the Excel sheet

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble updating a few cells inside an Excel sheet. The `PATCH` request goes through alright and everything looks fine but when I open the document its not updated.

The excel file is hosted in SharePoint, not OneDrive.

I'm using the Microsoft Graph via [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) and I can read the cells in question:

```
/v1.0/drives/{id}/list/items/{id}/driveItem/workbook/worksheets/{id}/range(address='B2:B3')
```

The write request returns success, but doesn't make any changes

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{id}/list/items/{id}/driveItem/workbook/worksheets/{id}/range(address='B2:B3')

{
  "values": [["foo bar"], ["hello world"]]
}
```

Response (200 OK) (omitted a few sensitive fields and a few for brevity)

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookRange",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookRange",
  "columnCount": 1,
  "cellCount": 2,
  "columnHidden": false,
  "rowHidden": false,
  "numberFormat": [["General"], ["General"]],
  "columnIndex": 1,
  "text": [["foo bar"], ["hello world"]],
  "hidden": false,
  "rowCount": 2,
  "rowIndex": 1,
  "valueTypes": [["String"], ["String"]],
  "values": [["foo bar"], ["hello world"]]
}
```

That's the response I'm expecting but when I open the Excel document, the cells are not updated.

I also tried using a `workbook-session`, but to no avail

1. Create session via

   ```
   http
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{id}/list/items/{id}/driveItem/workbook/createSession

   {
     "persistChanges": true
   }
   ```
2. Copy the `workbook-session-id`. The entire thing - it's crazy long!
3. Add the `workbook-session-id` header to the previous `PATCH` request and send.
4. Close the session via `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/list/items/{item-id}/driveItem/workbook/closeSession`
5. Check document, but it's unchanged

I also find the documentation a bit misleading. In the [Update Range doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) it says

> **Optional request headers**
>
> **Workbook-Session-Id** Workbook session Id that determines if changes are persisted or not. Optional.

Suggesting that if not used changes are not saved. However the [session docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-manage-sessions) says

> **Note**: The session header is not required for an Excel API to work.
>   However, we recommend that you use the session header to improve
>   performance. If you don't use a session header, changes made during
>   the API call **are** persisted to the file.

So why isn't it persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that the Excel file had a macro.

The call works for `.xlsm` files that do not have macros. Sadly the file in question was a `.xlsm` file with macros.